# If $D:A\to A$ is a derivation, what can be said about the range of $D$?

Tags: derivatives, differential-algebra

What can be said about the relation between the domain and range of a [derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28abstract_algebra%29) as a function?

If $A$ is the domain, any space of functions, what does $D(A)$ look like, where $D$ is a derivation? Is $D(A)=A$? I guess the function space should always be closed under multiplication and addition and then the Leibniz rule

$$D(ab)=D(a)b+aD(b)$$

should be unproblematic. It comes down to the definition of $D$ acting on the functions. In case that the domain is a priori "not as big" as the range, can one complete a function space by adding the closure w.r.t. a derivative?

And are there any categorical results? After all the cohomology business deals with mappings given by differential operators.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, you at least have that $D(A)$ is a subalgebra of $A$ if and only if $D^2(A)$ is a two-sided ideal of $A$, since for $a,b \in A$, $D(aD(b)) = D(a)D(b) + aD^2(b)$ and $D(D(a)b) = D^2(a)b + D(a)D(b)$.